# Просмотр HTML кода в google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему, когда я в google chrome нажимаю "просмотр кода страницы" - он для большинства сайтов выдает такой "упорядоченный" код.

А когда я делаю тоже самое для ютуба, то там просто месиво из "неупорядоченного" кода.

Для примера:

-HABR:
[image: HABR]

-youtube:

[image: youtube]

Comment: что значит _"упорядоченный" код_ и что значит _месиво из "неупорядоченного" кода_?

Comment: @Grundy♦, доабавил скриншоты.

Comment: Если уж занудствовать по поводу 'упорядочности' то у хабра с 9-15 строки нарушена вложенность. :D А так, как написал разраб так и отображается

Comment: @Константин, если совсем занудствовать, то не вложенность, а отступы, хотя они в принципе ни на что не влияют :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"просмотр кода страницы" отображает код так, как он был получен с сервера. Если в файле на сервере код был отформатирован - покажется отформатированный код.

В случае с youtube - показывается минифицированный код.

Comment: То есть гугл хром не строит дерево из тегов при просмотре кода страницы получается ?

Comment: Если вы будете смотреть таким образом показать код страницы то и в фаерфоксе вы тоже самое увидите. Хотите увидеть упорядоченность, смотрите через исследовать элемент.

Comment: @Optimus1, конкретно для "просмотра кода страницы" - отображается именно текст, который пришел с сервера.